# Disable font smoothing

Tags: windows, fonts, autoit

I am trying to make an AutoIt script that can enable and disable font smoothing. I have made this so far:

```
#RequireAdmin
RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\FontSmoothing", "REG_SZ", "0")
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone help me make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the value name parameter. In this case I believe the FontSmoothing part of the path you've given is actually the value name, so you'd want:

```
RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop", "FontSmoothing", "REG_SZ", "0")
```

This sort of error should have been very easy to spot by looking at the [RegWrite](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/RegWrite.htm) docs.

It's also worth considering whether this code is being run on a 64 bit computer, and if so use the 64 bit CURRENT_USER hive.

Comment: `If @error <> 0 Then MsgBox(0, "error in RegWrite", @error)`